# Python Como clickar em divs usando selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

**Estou tentando pegar empregos no google empregos e extrair dados para guadar em banco de dados ou em json.**

Sites: [GOOGLE EMPREGOS TELA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8BnN.png)
Notem como tenho no lado esquerdo uma lista com varios empregos e quando clico em algum ele exibe na tela ao lado informações mais detalhas, como faço pra cada emprego na lista da esquerda ser clickado e depois extrair o texto do titulo do emprego, como ali na imagem onde está escrito Estágio TI no lado de exibição

Meu codigo:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url1 = 'https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=Ja39X_nUIKif5OUPp6eUkAE&q=vagas+estagio+ti&oq=vagas+estagio+ti&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQsQMQgwEyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgAEEc6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BAgAEEM6DggAELEDEIMBEMcBEK8BOgsIABCxAxDHARCjAjoFCAAQsQM6BQguELEDOggIABDHARCvAVDeMFipTmClUGgCcAN4AIABnQKIAbUckgEGMC4xLjE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&uact=5&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZlb7fyJbuAhXWGbkGHdiZAEUQutcGKAB6BAgDEAQ#htivrt=jobs&fpstate=tldetail&htilrad=-1.0&htidocid=jN52cIGLUm9ZT0BQAAAAAA%3D%3D'

# Definindo Drive
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver')
driver.get(url1) # Entrando no url1

# Click

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit() # Fechando o driver
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Um elemento pode ser clicado no Selenium através da função `click()`:

```
elemento = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')
elemento.click()
```

Comment: Mas tem varios elementos com a mesma classe, como clico neles°

Comment: Nesse caso você pode usar `find_elements_by_class_name`, que irar retornar uma lista. Veja mais sobre aqui: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Então o meu problema era que retorna uma lista kkkk, obrigado